# Can I develop an app for hybris with ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid, sap-commerce-cloud

I know that hybrid has already provided these wrappers in the form of android SDK and ios SDK.

But what if I have to use ionic to develop an app for hybris? Can I use SDK that provided by hybris?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, one of the nice things of Hybris is that you can create your own extensions in Hybris to do what you want, I.E. create a custom UI, or make use of the web services to create a UI completely outside of hybris. I know there are projects which had a front end completely using Angular. You might struggle to find documentation on it as it is not OOTB, but Hybris won't prevent this sort of development.

It's possible for sure so just give it a go and try.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. We have decided to develop with ionic in the situation that Hybris sdk is not accessible for hybrid app. But as an app developer who is not familiar with Hybris, I am not sure that if a lot of web services are needed to develop without support of sdk, and performance will be impacted or not.

Comment: No problem, wish you guys the best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

just make sure to ENABLE this CUSTOM extension in Local.Properties.